# Неадекватно работает TinyMCE в Joomla 3.8.6

Tags: joomla, tinymce

Сайт на Joomla 3.8.6.
Стоят дефолтные редакторы "TinyMCE", "CodeMirror" и "Без редактора". Все три включены и опубликованы.

На фронтенде и в админке при редактировании модуля/материала используется CodeMirror. Естественно, заказчик хочет видеть там WYSIWYG-редактор.

В общих настройках сайта редактором по умолчанию стоит TinyMCE. В настройках самого плагина TinyMCE стоит порядок 0 - самый первый. У CodeMirror порядок стоит 6, у "Без редактора" - 2.

Проблема: несмотря на все эти настройки, и в админке, и на фронтенде используется только CodeMirror. Единственный способ задействовать TinyMCE - отключить CodeMirror нахрен. При этом а) система матерится при попытке отредактировать что-нибудь в шаблоне "включи CodeMirror" и отображает редактируемое в TinyMCE, что неприемлемо и б) на фронтенде показывает в "Без редактора", а если этот плагин отключить, вообще сообщает, что "не опубликован ни один плагин редактора". Но TinyMCE же включен и опубликован!

Что за хрень?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решен. Проблема оказалась в плагине Switch Editor, который был удален, но оставил в системе отходы жизнедеятельности. Пришлось вставить его обратно.